# My page refreshes when I click on a button

Tags: php, html

I have products page and each product has add to cart and more description button. more description is supposed to display extra description of the product ONLY. However, when it is clicked, it displays the extra description for a second and the page refreshes. I am focusing on the button only, so php can be ignored (unless it is the issue)

Here is the code for one of the products:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $xml = new DomDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
    $xml->load('products.xml');

    $pimage = 'Images/zucchini.jpg';
    $pname = 'Zucchini';
    $pquantity = $_POST['p-quantity'];
    $pprice = 1.76;

    $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("root")->item(0);

    $infoTag = $xml->createElement("info");
        $imgTag = $xml->createElement("img", $pimage);
        $nameTag = $xml->createElement("name", $pname);
        $priceTag = $xml->createElement("price", $pprice);
        $quantityTag = $xml->createElement("quantity", $pquantity);

        $infoTag->appendChild($imgTag);
        $infoTag->appendChild($nameTag);
        $infoTag->appendChild($priceTag);
        $infoTag->appendChild($quantityTag);

    $rootTag->appendChild($infoTag);
    $xml->save('products.xml');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Main-Stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../AislesDesign.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ProductPages.css">
    <script src="../Refresh.js" async></script>
    <script src="../productPages.js" async></script>


  <!-- Font Awesome --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  #more {display: none;}
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- header section -->
    <nav class="nav_bar">
        <a class="nav_logo" href="../index.php">
            <img src="../Images/Logo.png">
        </a>
  
        <form class="search">
          <input class="search_bar" type="search" placeholder="'Product'">
          <button class="search_button" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        <a class="cart_button" href="../ShoppingCart.php">
            <div class="cart_circle">
                <img src="../Images/cart-logo.png" />
            </div>
        </a>

    </nav>

<div class="row menu h-100 col-12 nopadding sticky-top">
       
    <div class="col-4 row text-center">
        <div class="dropdown menuText">
            <button class="dropbtn"><img class="dropdown-hamburger"src="../Images/hamburger-icon2.jpg" /><p class="nav-aisles">Aisles</p></button>
            <div class="col-3 row dropdown-content">
                <a href="../chickenAisle.html">Chicken</a>
                <a href="../meatAisle.html">Meat</a>
                <a href="../pastaAisle.html">Pasta</a>
                <a href="../fruitsAisle.html">Fruits</a>
                <a href="../vegetablesAisle.html">Vegetables</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 row menuText h-100">
        <a href="../index.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 row menuText h-100">
        <a>Locations</a>
    </div>
      
</div>

      <form method = "POST" action = "zucchiniProduct.php">
        <div class="product-border">
            <img class="images" name = "p-img" src="../Images/zucchini.jpg"
            alt="Image of zucchini">
            <div class="display">
                <h3 class="product-name-zucchini" name = "p-name">Zucchini</h3>
              <div class="moredescription_contain">
                <p class="product-description">1 vegetable (approx. 320g)<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">. Zucchini is a favourite vegetable for many people as it can be used in variety of dishes, especially during summer. It is very rich in vitamin C, folate and antioxidants and low in calories.</span></p>
              </div>
                <span class="product-price" name = "p-price"> $1.76</span>
                <p class="product-quantity"> Quantity: 
                    <input class="product-quantity-input" type="number" value="1" step="1" name = "p-quantity"></input>
                </p>
               
                <input type = "submit" name = "insert" value = "Add to Cart" class="button"></input>
            </form>
                <button onclick="clickDesc()" id="myBtn" class="button">More Description</button>
            </div>
        </div>
<script>
function clickDesc() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "More Description"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>
  
<div class="col-12 row h-100 nopadding footer">

    <div class="col-4 row footer-heading nopadding about">
        <h2>About Us</h2>
        <a href="#">Our Story</a>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="../P7.html">Customers</a>
    
    </div>

  
    
    <div class="col-4 row footer-heading nopadding contact-form">
        <h2>Customer Service</h2>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
        <a href="#">Find a Store</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 row footer-heading nopadding social-media">
        <h2>Social Media</h2>
        <a href="#">Instagram</a>
        <a href="#">Facebook</a>
        <a href="#">YouTube</a>
        <a href="#">Twitter</a>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="col-12 row nopadding">
      
        
        <div class="col-2 footer-bottom footer">
            &copy; 2022 poeatry.com 
    
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
    
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- footer section -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: set type of the button: `type="button"`

Comment: If the issue is just with the form/js function you should remove the PHP code and tag.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you opened this div `<div class="product-border">` and this div `<div class="display">` inside the form tag and then you closed it outside the form tag, which was causing the issue. To fix this issue close these divs properly inside the form tag.

Here's [the link](https://pastebin.com/UuMzu36h) to the fixed version of your code.